# how can we search record from mlm table structure

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with data.

```
ID  ParentID    NodeName
1   NULL    Administration
2   NULL    Master Data
3   NULL    Input Forms
4   NULL    User Reports
5   NULL    Other Pages
6   1   Add User
7   2   Product Maintanence
8   2   Product BOM
9   3   Expected Sales
10  3   Product BOM
11  4   Finance
12  4   Manufacturing
13  6   GOGS Report
14  7   Purchase History
15  8   Production Report
16  5   Google
17  5   Company Site
```

**Now I want to write a query which distinguish above query result as per parent-child relationship, as Parent_Original>>Parent1>>Child. If the database child goes upto n level it also result like  Parent n> Parent n-1> Parent n-2 > ... > Last Child**.

In above table scenario it result like.

```
Parent              Parent-1               Child

Administration      Add User               GOGS Report
Master Data         Product Maintanence    Purchase History
Master Data         Product BOM            Production Report
........... so on
```

*Can any one suggest me how can we do this. Any suggestion really appreciate.*

Comment: This sounds a bit like homework!  Have you looked at common table expressions (CTE)?

Comment: Yes I know! but could it be solved in single query, otherwise I have to break it parent by parent & running heavy loops. So that's why I was asking here.

Comment: Like @James L said.  Look at recursive CTEs.  That is what they are designed to do.  Not terribly efficient but they work.

Comment: Why do people 'downvote' without leaving any comment?  You'd think that with the time spent reading and deciding a post is lacking, that they'd take another moment to explain themselves - and perhaps teach a little in the process...

Comment: A CTE will not generate a dynamic number of columns.  If that is what you need, then see my answer below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this.  If you need the data for each relationship in its own column, and if the number of relationships won't exceed x levels deep (e.g., 5), then you can join the same table several times in a single query (see query 1).

If you don't need the data in separate columns, but can work with a single delimited value (e.g., "root parent -> next parent -> last parent -> child"), then you can use a CTE query to build the concatenated strings (see query 2).

```
declare @tbl table (id int, parentid int, nodename varchar(20))

insert into @tbl values
(1, NULL, 'Administration'),
(2, NULL, 'Master Data'),
(3, NULL, 'Input Forms'),
(4, NULL, 'User Reports'),
(5, NULL, 'Other Pages'),
(6, 1, 'Add User'),
(7, 2, 'Product Maintanence'),
(8, 2, 'Product BOM'),
(9, 3, 'Expected Sales'),
(10, 3, 'Product BOM'),
(11, 4, 'Finance'),
(12, 4, 'Manufacturing'),
(13, 6, 'GOGS Report'),
(14, 7, 'Purchase History'),
(15, 8, 'Production Report'),
(16, 5, 'Google'),
(17, 5, 'Company Site'),
(18, 13, 'Archived Data'),
(19, 13, 'Active Data'),
(20, 18, 'On Tape'),
(21, 18, 'On Disc')

/* query 1 */
select r.nodename as root
      ,c1.nodename as [child-1]
      ,c2.nodename as [child-2]
      ,c3.nodename as [child-3]
      ,c4.nodename as [child-4]
      ,c5.nodename as [child-5]
from   @tbl r
       left outer join @tbl c1 on r.id = c1.parentid
       left outer join @tbl c2 on c1.id = c2.parentid
       left outer join @tbl c3 on c2.id = c3.parentid
       left outer join @tbl c4 on c3.id = c4.parentid
       left outer join @tbl c5 on c4.id = c5.parentid
where  r.parentid is null
order by r.nodename, c1.nodename, c2.nodename, c3.nodename, c4.nodename, c5.nodename

/* query 2 */
;with cte(id, parentid, nodename) as (
  select id, parentid, cast(nodename as varchar(max))
  from   @tbl
  where  parentid is null

  union all

  select t.id, t.parentid, cast(cte.nodename + ' -> ' + t.nodename as varchar(max))
  from   @tbl t
         inner join cte on t.parentid = cte.id
)
select nodename
from   cte c1
where  not exists (
         select 1
         from   cte c2
         where  c1.id = c2.parentid
       )
order by nodename
```

### Query 1 Results

```
root                 child-1              child-2              child-3              child-4              child-5
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Administration       Add User             GOGS Report          Active Data          NULL                 NULL
Administration       Add User             GOGS Report          Archived Data        On Disc              NULL
Administration       Add User             GOGS Report          Archived Data        On Tape              NULL
Input Forms          Expected Sales       NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 NULL
Input Forms          Product BOM          NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 NULL
Master Data          Product BOM          Production Report    NULL                 NULL                 NULL
Master Data          Product Maintanence  Purchase History     NULL                 NULL                 NULL
Other Pages          Company Site         NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 NULL
Other Pages          Google               NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 NULL
User Reports         Finance              NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 NULL
User Reports         Manufacturing        NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 NULL
```

### Query 2 Results

```
nodename
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administration -> Add User -> GOGS Report -> Active Data
Administration -> Add User -> GOGS Report -> Archived Data -> On Disc
Administration -> Add User -> GOGS Report -> Archived Data -> On Tape
Input Forms -> Expected Sales
Input Forms -> Product BOM
Master Data -> Product BOM -> Production Report
Master Data -> Product Maintanence -> Purchase History
Other Pages -> Company Site
Other Pages -> Google
User Reports -> Finance
User Reports -> Manufacturing
```

Comment: Wonderful James ! I have no words for your solution. This is the exact solution what I'm looking for ! Nice Work brother. Keep it up.